# Spring Profiles not recognized in a Web Application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement Spring Profiles to load a specific class implementation based on the profile specified. The profile to use is specified as a property (spring.profiles.active) within a properties file included in the classpath.

Source here: https://github.com/overattribution/spring-profile-test

```
public interface MyService {
    public void doSomething();
}

@Service
@Profile("preprod")
public class MyServicePreProdImpl implements MyService {
    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServicePreProdImpl.class);
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        LOG.debug("Doing something in " + MyServicePreProdImpl.class.getName());
    }
}

@Service
@Profile("prod")
public class MyServiceProdImpl implements MyService {
    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceProdImpl.class);
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        LOG.debug("Doing something in " + MyServiceProdImpl.class.getName());
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:
No qualifying bean of type [com.example.profileservice.MyService] found for dependency.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE 1:**

I'm manually setting the active profile during web application initialization, but I'm still getting the "No qualifying bean found" error. Changes can be seen here: https://github.com/overattribution/spring-profile-test/commit/09175a10b28ea8e5a08b43ad1416431bcf094c9d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got it to work. Profiles need to be set within the root context (as opposed to servlet context) during web application initialization.  I have done so in my WebAppInitializer class like so:

https://github.com/overattribution/spring-profile-test/blob/f895a8bc67dc1f6ba2fcedb58b73a19cc5cf8cf7/src/main/java/com/example/config/WebAppInitializer.java

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    /**
     * Overriding to include setting active profile.
     */
    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
        Class<?>[] configClasses = getRootConfigClasses();
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(configClasses)) {
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootAppContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

            String[] activeProfiles = getActiveProfiles();
            rootAppContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(activeProfiles);

            rootAppContext.register(configClasses);
            return rootAppContext;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {
                ApplicationConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {
                WebMvcConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[] {characterEncodingFilter};
    }


    protected String[] getActiveProfiles() {
        PropertySource propertySource = null;
        try {
            propertySource = new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:application.properties");
            String profilesString = (String) propertySource.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME);
            return profilesString.split(",");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ResourceAccessException("application.properties is not available on the classpath");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> A profile is a named logical grouping that may be activated programmatically via ConfigurableEnvironment.setActiveProfiles(java.lang.String...) or declaratively through setting the spring.profiles.active property, usually through JVM system properties, as an environment variable, or for web applications as a Servlet context parameter in web.xml.

I would say that it is not possible to specify active profile as a property within your properties file unless you use Spring Boot that also enables you to set the active profile in `application.properties` file.

Try to use one of the options above.

Comment: I am migrating from a spring boot project which previously gave me this functionality. I wonder how they did it?

Comment: In Spring Boot you can also set the active profile in `application.properties`. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: So it seems to me I need to add some Java class that picks up the property from application.properties and then sets that value with ConfigurableEnvironment.setActiveProfiles(java.lang.String...)

Comment: If you do not require to have your active profile stored in a separate configuration file, I would say that it should be enough to uncomment `customizeRegistration` method in your `WebAppInitializer` class and set the respective profile.

Comment: After looking into WebAppInitializer parent classes, I decided to override createServletApplicationContext() so that I can register the active profile there. But, it's still giving me the "no bean found" error. I updated my original post with source.

Comment: Using the customizeRegistration method in WebAppInitializer also results in bean not found error.

Comment: Move your `Application` class from `com.example` package to `com.example.profileservice` package and try once more.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time pgiecek. I ended up solving my issue by reading the appropriate properties file and setting the profile in the root context.